# How to check whether domdocument has items

Tags: php

How to check whether domdocument has items

code:

```
 $iframe =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');


 foreach ($iframe as $if) {

    //how to check whether $if has items for
     // $if->item(0) so that I can access it without errors?
 }
```

Comment: `$if->item(0)` or `$iframe->item(0)`? See as well [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if the node has child nodes with [`hasChildNodes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php)

```
 foreach ($iframe as $if) {
    if ($if->hasChildNodes()) {
       // first child is $if->childNodes->item(0)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using like

`if($if -> hasChildNodes()) { ... }`